How do I know what method is called when swap to my ecr20 token?
I am reading ECR20 code: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20 and understand how it works. What I don't know is that what the method is called when swap other tokens to my ECR20 token.
The transfer method looks like doing the swap but not sure if it also calls other methods like approve, transferFrom etc. When the token is listed in a market place like https://dexscreener.com/. How does the marketplace calls those method?

In a Dex, the Dex is the one handling funds.
A Dex has liquidity pools in which are two tokens, the pair ( A & B).
When you want to do a swap you need to have approved enough allowance to the Dex, prior to the swap transaction, that will in turn  allow the Dex to call transferFrom() and send the tokens (A) from you to the pool and in exchange call transfer() to send the tokens (B) corresponding from the pool to you.

Is there any offical doc to explain all of those logic? If I want to publish a token on dex, what interface should I implement?

This happens automatically. If you have to approve a token most Dexs will trigger a approve() event for you to approve, and then trigger the transferFrom() and transfer() functions, which will do what they are supposed to do: transfer token A TO you and transfer token B FROM you.
The docu ? Maybe you can read how ERC20 works ? Read the EIP20 ?

I have read ERC20 code from openzepplin. but what I don't understand is the different between Dexs and my contract. Does Dexs ever call any methods from my contract? do I need to implement ERC20 as well?

Well you aren't very clear.
First of all don't read openzeppelin code, read EIP20 https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20.
Second, WHAT is your contract ? You never talked about YOUR contract.
You should read the code of a Dex to understand. Dex do indeed call the ERC20 contracts to do the transfers, that's why they need to have the appropriate allowance beforehand to be allowed to call transferFrom() in your stead.

I'd like to know the internal logic when swap a token to another token via dex.

Then you need to read the swap function used by the dex you are using..
Here is the uniswapv2 swap() for instance: https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/ee547b17853e71ed4e0101ccfd52e70d5acded58/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol#L159

it seems I read a wrong code. I read the dex contract code from etherscan:
https://etherscan.io/token/0x497bAEF294c11a5f0f5Bea3f2AdB3073DB448B56#code. it is just a openzepplin implementaion of ECR20

This is indeed just an ERC20 called "Dex" not a Decentralized exchange.
In any case, here is the comment section, it is not made for lengthy conversation.

The swapping doesn't happen inside the token contract. It happens inside the DEX contracts and the functions used are the approve and transferFrom.
Before calling the swap function, we need to approve the swap contract to transfer the tokens. Once approved, we call the swap function and inside the swap function, the DEX contract calls transferFrom to transfer the tokens from our wallet to itself.
Hence whenever we swap we have to sign two transactions, one for approval and the other for the swap.
EDIT (as per the comment):

Does it mean I need to purchase dex token in order to call approve and transferFrom? What methods does dex call my ERC20 contrac

You don't call the transferFrom, you just call the swap function and it then calls transferFrom, for both approve and swap you would need to pay gas fees (depends on the protocol, if they are sponsoring the gas fees then you don't need to pay).

in other words, do I need to implement ERC20 in order to exchange my token with other tokens via dex platform?

Your token should be ERC20, that's it.

Is there any offical doc to explain all of those logic? If I want to publish a token on dex, what interface should I implement

If you wanna add a token on a dex, you don't need anything else other than just the ERC20 interface, you also don't need to worry about the swapping function. You just need to create a liquidity pool of the token you wanna add and the other token to which your token will trade, it can be ether, any native currency, or any other ERC20 token.

Does it mean I need to purchase dex token in order to call approve and transferFrom? What methods does dex call my ERC20 contract? in other words, do I need to implement ERC20 in order to exchange my token with other tokens via dex platform?

To clarify how your ERC20 token is handled during a swap transaction on platforms such as those listed on DEX Screener, let's look deeper into the mechanics of ERC20 token interactions within a DEX environment.
Token Swap Mechanisms in DEXs
1. ERC20 Token Standards
Firstly, it's important to grasp the core methods defined by the ERC20 standard, which you are looking into via the OpenZeppelin documentation. The primary methods relevant here are:

approve(address spender, uint256 amount): This method allows a third party (in your case, the DEX) to withdraw tokens up to the amount from your account and is crucial for enabling transactions without requiring direct token transfers from the token holder.
transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount): Directly transfers amount of tokens to recipient.
transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount): Allows a third party (pre-approved via approve) to transfer tokens on behalf of sender to recipient.

2. Interaction Flow When Swapping Tokens
When you swap tokens (say, Token A for Token B) on a DEX, the process typically involves the following steps:

Approval: Before the swap can occur, you must authorize the DEX to handle (withdraw) your tokens. This is done by calling the approve method, setting the DEX's address as the spender and specifying the maximum amount of your tokens (Token A) that the DEX is allowed to manage.
approve(dexAddress, tokenAmount)


Swap Execution: Once approval is granted, the actual swap is initiated typically through a function specific to the DEX, not directly through standard ERC20 methods. This function, let's call it swapTokensForTokens, will handle the logic required to exchange Token A for Token B.
During this operation:

The DEX uses transferFrom to move the specified amount of Token A from your wallet to its liquidity pool.
Simultaneously, Token B is sent from the liquidity pool to your wallet using transfer.

transferFrom(yourAddress, poolAddress, amountOfTokenA)
transfer(poolAddress, yourAddress, amountOfTokenB)



3. Considerations for Different DEXs
Different DEXs might implement additional methods or steps specific to their platform. For instance, some might use a combination of transfer and transferFrom for handling transaction fees or for special trading features like slippage protection. It is important to read the specific smart contract or API documentation of the DEX you are using to understand these details.
*The full text of this answer was passed through GPT-4 with the prompt (notifying according to the policy https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/gen-ai-policy): "Correct the grammatical errors without changing the actual meaning of the text"
